# How easy is to get a license to let a private home to tourists on a short term basis?

Tags: rental, spain

I'm not Spanish, but I'd like to live in Spain as an expatriate by buying e.g. a 5-6 bedroom flat in Spain, living in one room, and renting the other rooms, as it seems a lot of people are doing that already.

But I heard that it's illegal in Spain for private homes to be let to tourists on a short term basis, and that the government has voted to update the Urban Rental Law (LAU) which will hand regulation of the rental area to the regional authorities.

Therefore, where I can apply for the license, how much can it cost and what's the risk that after buying the property, I won't get a license? One of the estate agencies in Barcelona told me that people normally don't get a short-term license easily.

Links:

- [Home rentals crackdown in Spain](http://www.theolivepress.es/spain-news/2013/04/16/home-rentals-crackdown/)
- [Dispelling the myths about holiday rental licences in Spain](http://www.spain-holiday.com/rentalbuzz/dispelling-the-myths-about-holiday-rental-licences-in-spain)
- [Ending with illegal rental properties for tourists in Spain](http://propertymarbellaapartments.com/blog/2013/04/18/ending-with-illegal-rental-properties-for-tourists-in-spain/)
- [Airbnb Fined $40,000 In Spain For Short-Term Room Rentals](http://www.businessinsider.com/r-airbnb-fined-in-catalonia-over-short-term-room-lets-2014-07)

Comment: As a problem that affects both locals and expats equally, this is likely off-topic - it's not specific to expats.

Comment: -1, because apartments and homes should not be used in this way, and we should discourage such use. People in Spain need places to live. If you're not willing to just let people live with you for expenses-only (which you should - having chosen to occupy a large house for some reason), at least let the space out for a fair low price to people who need a long-term place to stay. Don't try to make a quick buck like this.